# Неправильно устанавливается размер окна в Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Есть два класса. Один описывает настроенный `JFrame`, другой создаёт его экземпляр.
Я пытался установить размер окна на `1000х500` с помощью `setSize(1000,500)`. Пустое окно создаётся, но имеет размер рабочей области `985х450`. Код ниже.

Главный класс:

```
public class Main {
static Window window;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    window = new Window();
}
```

Класс с JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Window extends JFrame {
public Window() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(1000,500);
    setLocation((screenSize.width-1000)/2, (screenSize.height-800)/2);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Что я делаю не так и как можно исправить проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как вы размер рабочей области определили?

Comment: Возможно должно помочь `super.pack(); super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`допишите в конец. Если через `setSize` не выставит, напишите: `super.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));`

Comment: @And 

Пишу
        `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
        setLayout(null);
        super.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
        setLocation((screenSize.width-1000)/2, (screenSize.height-500)/2);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        super.pack();
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Всё равно ставится `985х460`

Comment: @ИмяФамилия в яндекс скриншотах при выделении области показывается её размер :)))

Comment: @zEvilCube странно, рабочая область всегда меньше окна из-за рамки, но не настолько. Аналогичный код у меня даёт нормальный результат.